# Enum pointer parameter in C

Tags: c, pointers, enums

I'm writing some testing functions for a project. The test function takes a function pointer, an expected value and a test value and checks them:

```
int TestIntInIntOut(int (*func)(int val), int expected, int testvalue);
```

However, I'm also testing functions which can take an enum as a parameter or as an exit value.

Suppose the following:

```
typedef enum { Zero, One, Two } MyEnum;
```

Is there a way I can pass an entire enum as a type? For **any** enum. For example:

```
int TestIntInEnumOut(?enum? (*func)(int val), ?enum? expected, int testvalue);
```

or

```
int TestEnumInIntOut(int (*func)(?enum? val), int expected, ?enum? testvalue);
```

(Sort of like what a generic in C# would allow.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do you mean any enum, or just `MyEnum`?

If you only need a function to support `MyEnum`, you could do:

```
int TestEnumInIntOut(int (*func)(MyEnum val), int expected, MyEnum testvalue);
```

Otherwise you probably can't do it in C, with much type safety.  But an enum is essentially the same as an int, so you could just treat them all as `int` types.  If the type safety is necessary, consider providing different integer value ranges for different enum types.

Comment: It would be for any enum, yes.

Comment: Missed that part in my (now deleted) answer below.  Agree with @Rob.

Answer (score 0):

Not directly an answer to your question, however as you said you are writing some test functions: You might want to have a look at [googletest](http://code.google.com/p/googletest/) or [cppunit](http://sourceforge.net/projects/cppunit/) - could save you some trouble.